# ImportJSON to Google Sheets got returned code 503. Truncated server response

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, http-status-code-503

I am a beginner in terms of using Google Scripts/any coding languages but could really do with some help in automating data import from the Environment Agency Real-Time data monitoring API. The API addresses are below:

```
https://cryptocars.me/info?
```

I have tried using the following IMPORTJSON code from

```
function setTrigger() {

deleteTriggers();  
var times =[[21,59]]; 
times.forEach(t_el => scheduledTrigger(t_el[0],t_el[1]));
}

function scheduledTrigger(hours,minutes){

var today_D = new Date();  
var year = today_D.getFullYear();
var month = today_D.getMonth();
var day = today_D.getDate();

pars = [year,month,day,hours,minutes];

var scheduled_D = new Date(...pars);
var hours_remain=Math.abs(scheduled_D - today_D) / 36e5;
ScriptApp.newTrigger("function_Triggered")
.timeBased()
.after(hours_remain * 60 *60 * 1000)
.create()
}

function deleteTriggers() {

var triggers = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers();
for (var i = 0; i < triggers.length; i++) {
if (   triggers[i].getHandlerFunction() == "function_Triggered") {
  ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(triggers[i]);
}
}
}

function function_Triggered() {
var s = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
var lastRow = s.getLastRow()+1


s.getRange(lastRow,1).setValue(new Date())

var url = s.getRange('B1').getValue()
var data = s.getRange('B2').getValue()
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var content = res.getContentText();
var json = JSON.parse(content);
s.getRange(lastRow,2).setValue(eval(json[data]))

var url = s.getRange('C1').getValue()
var data = s.getRange('C2').getValue()
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var content = res.getContentText();
var json = JSON.parse(content);
s.getRange(lastRow,3).setValue(eval(json[data]))

var url = s.getRange('D1').getValue()
var data = s.getRange('D2').getValue()
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var content = res.getContentText();
var json = JSON.parse(content);
s.getRange(lastRow,4).setValue(eval(json[data]))


var url = s.getRange('E1').getValue()
var data = s.getRange('E2').getValue()
var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
var content = res.getContentText();
var json = JSON.parse(content);
s.getRange(lastRow,5).setValue(eval(json[data]))



function Players(){
var dt= new Date();
var time_stamp= dt.toLocaleTimeString();
var cellVal= '=value(IMPORTDATA("https://cryptocars.me/info?","players","'+time_stamp+'"))';
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('B3').setValue(cellVal);
}


function Cars(){
var dt= new Date();
var time_stamp= dt.toLocaleTimeString();
var cellVal= '=IMPORTJSON("https://cryptocars.me/info?","cars","'+time_stamp+'")';
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('C3').setValue(cellVal);
}

function Transactions(){
var dt= new Date();
var time_stamp= dt.toLocaleTimeString();
var cellVal= '=value(IMPORTJSON("https://cryptocars.me/info?","trxs","'+time_stamp+'"))';
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('D3').setValue(cellVal);
}


function Gas(){
var dt= new Date();
var time_stamp= dt.toLocaleTimeString();
var cellVal= '=value(IMPORTJSON("https://cryptocars.me/info?","gas","'+time_stamp+'"))';
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('E3').setValue(cellVal);
}

function IMPORTJSON(url,xpath){

try{
  // /rates/EUR
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var content = res.getContentText();
  var json = JSON.parse(content);
  
  var patharray = xpath.split("/");
  //Logger.log(patharray);
  
  for(var i=0;i<patharray.length;i++){
    json = json[patharray[i]];
  }
  
  //Logger.log(typeof(json));
  
  if(typeof(json) === "undefined"){
    return "Node Not Available";
  } else if(typeof(json) === "object"){
    var tempArr = [];
    
    for(var obj in json){
      tempArr.push([obj,json[obj]]);
    }
    return tempArr;
  } else if(typeof(json) !== "object") {
    return json;
  }
}
catch(err){
    return "Error getting data";  
}
}

}
```

However, from what I understand, this is a generic code which allows me to use the IMPORTJSON function within Google Sheets. But i got this error

```
Exception: Request failed for https://cryptocars.me returned code 503. Truncated server response: <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<me... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
function_Triggered  @ CCAR.gs:44
```

Kindy to help fix it.

Comment: The website seems to be blocking automated requests using cloudflare ddos.

Comment: I confirm : 
Before loading, the website checks your browser. Since google is asking for you, the website is blocking the request.

Comment: I also reproduced that in Postman and I got the same issue `503Service Unavailable`. You may consult cryptocars to check how you can use their API